# Tree Grid with search

Tags: extjs4

I have tree Grid with more data. I want to do

1] Search on Grid's store.

2] Improve the performance as some times I get data in 10,000 also.

Please suggest me the best way to do this.

Comment: About Search, I think you can use `filter`. However if the data are big, `filter` on client-side is applied on the records loaded. Can use `remoteFilter` to apply searching on server-side but actually I have not tried it yet

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Mode TreeGrid?

Many Controls support this method of opperation.

you can try customizing **SourceGrid** to support Tree List, but it is opensource, free, and Licensed under the Great MIT,
[SourceGrid](http://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/)...
it is nice, fast, though it ain't as fancy as others.

.

There is also **ObjectListView** 
[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html)
but i never get to use it cause it uses GPL which is the licensing equivalent to Cancer!

Best of luck

there are many more: search **virtual Tree List View** and you find them

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am using Extjs 4.0.7 version. Please suggest If it is possible in this version and what is the best approach to do this